# What is the best way to import SVG using React.JS

Tags: reactjs, svg

My team and I are building a react application and we want to import SVGs not as a string so we'll have the ability to use it as a component.

Since we've installed the project using CRA, SVGR is already installed and is in webpack configuration.

We wanted to know if there's any other way to import the SVG file and not to use the `import {ReactComponent as Logo} from '../path'` but use something like `import Logo from '../path'`.

Also is there any benefits from using it that way?
Actually we're able to import it the way we want but we can't use it outside of an image tag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can create Your custom Component like

```
const ArrowIcon = (props)=>{
  return (
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" {...props}>
  <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={2} d="M13 9l3 3m0 0l-3 3m3-3H8m13 0a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
</svg>
)
}
```

**Warning:**
Careful with Props of SVG. because In React, SVG Attributes may vary from SVG in HTML!

You can use it by

```
import ArrowIcon from "path/to/svgComponent"

const SimpleReact = ()=>{
  return (
    <div>
      Arrow Icon
      <ArrowIcon className="class" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I hope It would work fine ;-)

You can also try `SVGR` which an awesome library to work with React and SVG.
You can download it with

```
yarn add -D @svgr/cli
```

Transforms a single file by specifying file as the single argument.

```
npx @svgr/cli -- icons/clock-icon.svg
```

You can find more in their Official Docs Link [here](https://react-svgr.com/docs/cli/)

Comment: The issue is that we have many SVG icons that we have to add to our project and we don't want to create a TSX file for all of them.
Is there a way you know to import directly the SVG files?

Answer (score 2):

Usually I'm using this package [react-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg), which you can use with Styled Components.

I create a component with it like so:

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components"
import { ReactSVG } from "react-svg"

const IconStyled = styled(ReactSVG)`
    display: inline-flex;
    width: ${props => `${props.size}px`};
    height: ${props => `${props.size}px`};
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    span {
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    svg {
        fill: black;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    path {
        fill: ${props => props.color};
    }
`

export default function Icon(props) {
    return (
        <IconStyled
            src= {`/icons/${props.name}.svg`}
            color={props.color || "currentColor"}
            size={props.size}
            wrapper="span"
            {...props}
        />
    )
}
```

Then, put all the `.svg` files inside the public folder, and just use them like this:

```
<Icon name="name-of-icon" size={24} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/docs/cli/#transform-a-whole-directory) to import your SVGs as react components.
It has a lot of plugins for different bundlers.

I recently used the SVGR plugin in vite.js. it's very easy to use and doesn't need to run scripts.

but also you can convert your SVG files with SVGR/cli. https://react-svgr.com/docs/cli/

To convert the whole directory of SVG to react components use this script:

`npx @svgr/cli --out-dir dist -- icons`

for more information check the docs: https://react-svgr.com/

Answer (score 1):

As u said, if u are using `create-react-app` u can simply do:

```
import { ReactComponent as YourIcon } from "your-icon.svg"
```

then u can use it as normal React component:

```
<YourIcon />
```

I think it's the easiest and the cleanest way to handle `.svg` files.